# Codigniter Javascript nested Jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, codeigniter

My requirnment is if data1[count1].result_type > 0 then the td will be a drop down list from a datatable. Nut is i try this, the output is like this, all the required options are comming to a single selectbox insted of the relevent row. And the result comes to the very last row.
[image]

The desired result would be two dropdowns at the last two rows. The wanted result options all together in the one dropdown. How can I solve this?

```js
$('#bill_no_search').click(function() {
  {
    $("#data_table_one tbody").html("");
    var barcode = $('#barcode_no').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/Lab_and_lab_office/get_barcode_to_bill_no'); ?>",
      data: {
        barcode: barcode
      },
      method: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(data) {

        var bill_no = data.bill_no;
        console.log(bill_no)
        $.ajax({

          url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/Lab_and_lab_office/resulting'); ?>",
          data: {
            bill_no: bill_no
          },
          method: "POST",
          dataType: "JSON",
          success: function(data) {



            for (var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {

              var element_id = data[count].element_id;
              var ct = 'screen' + count + '';
              var bt = 'td' + count + ''
              var result = 'result' + count + ''

              $('#data_table_one tbody').append(
                '<tr>' +

                '<td >' + (count + 1) + '</td>' +
                '<td >' + data[count].billing_element_result_id + '</td>' +
                '<td >' + data[count].bill_no + '</td>' +
                '<td >' + data[count].processor_id + '</td>' +
                '<td >' + data[count].test_processor_display_name + '</td>' +
                '<td >' + data[count].test_code + '</td>' +
                '<td >' + data[count].test_details + '</td>' +

                '<td contenteditable=true id="result' + count + '">' + data[count].result + '</td>' +
                '<td id="td' + count + '" contenteditable=true><select id="screen' + count + '" style="display:none"></select></td>' +

                '<td contenteditable=true id="resultcell">' + data[count].result + '</td>' +

                '</tr>'

              );

              console.log(ct)


              $.ajax({

                url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/Lab_and_lab_office/get_result_type'); ?>",
                data: {
                  element_id: element_id
                },
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data1) {


                  for (var count1 = 0; count1 < data1.length; count1++) {

                    if (data1[count1].result_type > 0) {

                      document.getElementById(ct).style.display = "block";
                      $('#' + ct + '').append(

                        '<option>' + data1[count1].result_options + '</option>'

                      );
                      document.getElementById(bt).contentEditable = "false";
                      document.getElementById(result).contentEditable = "false";

                    }
                    console.log(ct)
                  }
                }
              })
            }
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Too many nested ajax

Comment: @mplungjan - Yes. One is to grub the bill number, second one is to get the results and the third one is for the dropdown results of the previous result. How can I do it without this much nested ajax??